# c# Array not printing out contents

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array in which the user will insert a 5 jobs which include description, hours it takes to complete and hourly pay. Apologies for the newbie question as I'm new to this language. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  private static void EnterJobs()
    {

        //string inputString;
        for (int i = 0; i < jobArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Job job = new Job();

            Console.WriteLine("Job " + i);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a job description.");
            job.Description = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of hours required to complete the job.");
            job.hoursToComplete = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the hourly rate for the job.");
            job.hourlyRate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            jobArray[i] = job;
        }
```

When I try to print out the contents of the array it prints out

```
DemoJobs.Job
DemoJobs.Job
DemoJobs.Job
DemoJobs.Job
DemoJobs.Job
```

using this loop

```
        for (int i = 0; i < jobArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(jobArray[i]);
        }
```

Comment: How should .Net know what you want a `Job` type to look like on the console? You need a ToString() method that tells it.

Comment: You're treating a class like a single variable, when each Job has different properties or fields (or both). Each one of those needs to be handled. You can Console.WriteLine(jobArray[0].Job.Description) though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just jotted this up in Notepad, but in your Job class you should have something like the following for your program to know what to print:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Description + ", Hours: " + this.Hours.ToString() + ", Rate: " + this.Rate.ToString(); 
}
```

Then you'd do

```
Console.WriteLine(job1.ToString());
```

Comment: or jobArray[0].ToString() ;-)